# Types Accepted by "file" HTML Input Element's Preexisting MIME Types

Tags: html, input, web

I am curious if there's a list of valid image types (essentially extensions) accepted by using `image/*` for an `input`'s `accept` attribute. Example:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

What extensions would be valid for this? Likewise, for the other two, `audio/*` and `video/*`. Thank you!

Comment: You may check out [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility) (scroll down to `audio/*` row) for some reference. But as Mr. Alien points out, this may not be a consistent list across browsers and OSs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the way you can allow different filetypes for `accept` attribute.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" />
```

Same way you can allow audio and video files as well.

Follow this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type

You can check which filetypes are allowed.

Comment: I just want to know how the default extensions provided by `image/*` are determined and possibly if there's a static list.

Comment: This still needs to be validated on the php side. You can simply erase that in firebug or chrome inspect and upload any file.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work properly across all browsers. Mozilla Firefox will allow `*.jpg` but not `*.jpeg`, for example.